# Login User in Background on Startup?

Tags: windows-10

I want a user to be logged in when Windows starts up. But I still want the password to be required. When the server starts it should just log the user in the background, so that all their startup programs and such also begin. Is this possible to do? The only option I seem to be able to find logs the user in fully without needing a password, which is not what I want.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you really trying to accomplish? Running some programs on startup? That is what task scheduler is for.

Comment: In a way yes that's what I want. If I use task scheduler though, when the user logs in, they can't see the started application. They have no way to interact with it, even if the application is started using their user's login.

Comment: The following should work in theory. I haven't yet tried it. I will report more once I tried it in a VM. The two things that pop out at me is that the task will have to be scheduled for all user accounts to be "secure" and there may exist a short period between boot and the task where a malicious actor may be able to hijack an account ... but I lack sufficient knowledge to cite any specific malicious actor risks; the RDP suggestion seems to be more secure in this respect. https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/how-to-automatically-login-to-windows-and-then-lock-the-workstation/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to do this directly.  In order to login and start programs in the background, a user session has to be created, which requires the user to actually log in to a desktop session.

It *might* be possible to do this though.  Emphasis on *might*.  I havent tried this, so I dont know if it will work.  You could script a remote desktop session that is run on booting the server.  I dont know if you can do this with a RDP file, a 3rd party program, or a script.  You would have to experiment. If it is successful, whenever that user logs in, it will take over the remote desktop session.  Obviously, you need to deal with the timeout issues, security, etc.

Comment: Yah that isn't ideal to use RDP, was hoping there was a simpler method.